# How can I force an emoji design (twitter, microsoft, etc) on my website?

Tags: twitter, styles, emoji

I'm using emojis on a website I'm developing. I would like them to use Twitter style. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) project and implement the script in the `<head>` of your website.

```
<script src="//twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/twemoji.min.js?2.7"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have a java trigger or jquery trigger set up when a textarea or textbox loads/changes its text content to replace things like :) and :( with the emojis grabbed from those other services. custom font packs for text-replacement might be a good idea here, or absolutely positioned objects, perhaps.